# Ansi 40 (Black Background) does not work in WSL using Windows Terminal

Tags: terminal, colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but i'm trying to run [ArchWSL](https://github.com/yuk7/ArchWSL) with [Microsoft Terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal) and to style it as I have my actual Arch instalation. I'm trying to "port" [base16 Flat Light](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-iterm2/blob/master/base16-flat.light.itermcolors) to the Terminal.

This is the Color Scheme I have made:

```
{
    "background": "#ECF0F1",
    "black": "#2C3E50",
    "blue": "#3498DB",
    "brightBlack": "#95A5A6",
    "brightBlue": "#3498DB",
    "brightCyan": "#1ABC9C",
    "brightGreen": "#2ECC71",
    "brightPurple": "#9B59B6",
    "brightRed": "#E74C3C",
    "brightWhite": "#ECF0F1",
    "brightYellow": "#F1C40F",
    "cyan": "#1ABC9C",
    "foreground": "#7F8C8D",
    "green": "#2ECC71",
    "name": "Flat Light",
    "purple": "#9B59B6",
    "red": "#E74C3C",
    "white": "#e0e0e0",
    "yellow": "#F1C40F"
}
```

Now my problem is that the black is either transparent (nonexisting) or the same color as the background.

[image: not a black background]

As you can see from the image, the background aswell as the admin@... (that is usually also black) is not black, even though if I run the same command on my Arch Installation it is the same color as the font color.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Windows Terminal program you are using is BETA.  Bugs are expected and you apparently found one... or not.. a matter of opinion.

It appears that Terminal responds to the black code by resetting the background to the default for that terminal.  I think that this is a bug by posix standards but it is up to a given terminal on how it wants to display colors.. so maybe not.  Not my war.

One other thing.. in a Linux terminal, instead of using escape codes, **use the linux command**  [tput](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php) .  It isn't as messy and least leaves a layer to deal with terminal compatability.  On terms that don't support colors, your codes are stripped out.. win, win.

What I found testing this (just now) is that the Microsoft terminal responds to a whole lot of colors and BLACK is 0 for foreground and 16 (yes 16) for background.  If you use 0, you will get your original background color back.

**The following snippet shows some of the supported colors for the new terminal as it is.  You have to stretch the terminal wide for the formatting to not suck.**

```
    for fg_color in {0..7}; do
        set_foreground=$(tput setaf $fg_color)
        for bg_color in {0..16}; do
            set_background=$(tput setab $bg_color)
            echo -n $set_background$set_foreground
            printf ' F:%s B:%s ' $fg_color $bg_color
        done
        echo $(tput sgr0)
    done
```

Here is what that looks like on my display.  The first index shows as BLACK because that was the default for that terminal
[image]

I would have made the range bigger to show ALL of the possible colors but I was to lazy to code up the column formatting required.

I hope this helps.